# Team Foundation Server Event all collections

Tags: .net, wcf, events, tfs, workitem

I'm trying to connect Team Foundation Server with BizTalk.

BizTalk should do something when a work item changed. in order to do this I need to make a WCF that listen to the event alert from the TFS server.

my problem is that the subscribe function only listen to one TFS Project Collection. The company has so many project collections.

how can I make the WCF, so that it listens to the Event alert from ALL project colletions? Is there a central Event manager or something like that?

thank you in advance.

Abi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this forum, he inderstand how subscribe tfs notification

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx